# Login/Register pop up form - backend

Tags: php, html, authentication, form-submit, backend

I am working on my first website so please pardon my lack of knowledge.
I have an index.html file with a pop up login/register modal using bootstrap3 and all the pages of my website are built in html. I have an sql database table also set up on the server using PHPmyadmin. After some research on the web I noticed that its all done with php and the index.html is converted to index.php Now my question is :

> Blockquote

How do i get the login/register pop-up form functional with html? Do I have to necessarily convert my index.html to index.php for the form to function? What are the flaws of converting index.html to index.php Or is there another way?

Again please pardon my inexperience.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 possibilities in this case :

1. "Converting" your file in a `.php`, which will be readable and interpreted by your server to get back some information located in your server side like database information or server information (in your case, you will verify the user/password by querying your database, php is absolutely needed). PhP return in any case HTML, so you can write HTML in a `.php` file.
2. Using AJAX, you don't have to convert YOUR html file in php, but another `.php` file containing all the procedure to connect, select, and return the result of the username/password entered, will be needed.